# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$serie' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

This is the code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT idEquipos, Nombre, fk_idTipo, Marca, Modelo, Serie, assetcode, fecha_alta, resp_alta FROM tbl_equipos where Serie = '$serie'';
```

Comment: You have to learn how to concatenate: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: let me check it. Thanks